# change the color of a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm trying to change the colour of a div using 'jQuery', but don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
function objectPosition() {
$('#OutlineX1').css("color","blue");
}
```

Comment: Color changes the text color. If you want to change background-color, use `background-color`.

Answer (score 4):

What you're stating right now is to change the text `color` of the div. If that's what you want, then make sure you're selecting the correct element. If you want to change the background color, however, then use `background-color` instead of `color`.

Comment: oh my god thank you so much, what a dumb mistake :)

Comment: No problem, everyone makes mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

use `background-color` instead of `color`, `color` attribute is  using for change font color. if you have doubt regarding  `css()` refer [this](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
function objectPosition() {
$('#OutlineX1').css("background-color","blue");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think use `addClass` is better.

```
changeColor {
  background-color: 'blue';
}

function objectPosition() {
  $('#OutlineX1').addClass('changeColor');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, you can use so many effects with this.but for basic I used only one.if you want more thant that tell me.I have linked jquery online.if you want you can use offline also.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 body{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;

 }

 div.mycolor{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
 }
</style>

<body>
 <div class="mycolor">
  
 </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".mycolor").click(function(){
   $(this).css({"background-color":"orange"},1000);
  });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

in here when your click on your red div, it will change it's color to orange.if you want more than this tell me.hope this will help to you.